# Chain rule for vector valued function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

I am stuck with seemingly simple chain rule application. Consider this vector valued function:

$f(\alpha,\beta)=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha^{2} \\ -\beta\end{pmatrix}$

Now I need to compute following derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}(f\circ f)'$$

According to chain rule, that should be something like:

$f'(f))\cdot f'=\begin{pmatrix}2f \\ -1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$

However, this results in multiplying two column vectors together, which is not possible.

Where am I doing the mistake? Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update (more complicated case):

I have functions that map 2D points to another 2D points, the point is defined as:

$\mathbb{x}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$

Now there is one linear mapping:

$P(\mathbb{x}|a,b,c,d)=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\mathbb{x}$

And one non-linear:

$L(\mathbb{x}|\kappa)=\begin{pmatrix}x^{2}\kappa \\ xy\kappa\end{pmatrix}$

Now how to compute gradient of the function:

$p=L(P\mathbb{x})$ ?

the gradient should be:

$\nabla p=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \kappa} \end{pmatrix}$

now the single element of the gradient should be computable using chain rule, e.g.:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}p=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}L(P\mathbb{x})\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial a}P\mathbb{x}$

The first element of the product will become 2-vector and the second also...

Furthermore, if I go for total derivatives, since there are only 2 coordinates (x,y) and 5 variables, the Jacobians would be $2\times 5$ and therefore cannot be multiplied together.

Comment: Your map is $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, so how can you compose $f$ with itself?

Comment: @Mnifldz I have adjusted the question. I am really stuck with this entire day - all the tutorials show just simple examples and not when we are composing two or more functions that map vectors to vectors.

Comment: You have the form of $f'$ wrong - it should be a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: To compose two functions, the output of one must be 'compatible' with the input of the other.

Comment: @Dom Why $f'$ should be a matrix and $f'(f)$ not? Why simple derivative of a vector yields a matrix? I am totally confused with this.

Comment: $f'(f)$ should be a matrix as well. Whenever you have a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, it's derivative will be a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: @Dom I wrote a question giving the problem more context - I hope this will make some sense for where I am going from: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131157/least-squares-minimization-of-point-cloud-distances

Comment: We have that $f'(\alpha,\beta)=\left(\begin{matrix}2\alpha&0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right)$ then $(f\circ f)(\alpha,\beta)=\left(\begin{matrix}\alpha^4\\\beta\end{matrix}\right)$ which then has derivative $\left(\begin{matrix}4\alpha^3&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$ and if you only care about the $\alpha$ derivative you can see it is just $\left(\begin{matrix}4\alpha^3\\0\end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: I haven't used the chain rule above, but to do that you would take $f'(f(\alpha,\beta))=\left(\begin{matrix}2\alpha^2&0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do out the example you mention in this third version of your question.

$P$ is a function $P:\mathbb{R}^6\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$P\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\a\\b\\c\\d
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ax+by\\cx+dy
\end{pmatrix}$$
$L$ is a function $:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$L\begin{pmatrix}
\kappa\\x\\y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x^2\kappa\\xy\kappa
\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore $L$ and $P$ **cannot be composed**. *However*, for any **given** value of $\kappa$ you can form the function $L_\kappa:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$; for example if $\kappa=3$, then the function $L_3$ is defined by
$$L_3\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
3x^2\\ 3xy
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $P$ can be composed with any choice of these functions to form $(L_\kappa\circ P):\mathbb{R}^6\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Here are the derivatives: (I am using the $0$ subscripts to encourage you to think of them all as fixed numbers.)

$$P'\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\y_0\\a_0\\b_0\\c_0\\d_0
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & b_0 & x_0 & y_0 & 0 & 0\\
c_0 & d_0 & 0 & 0 & x_0 & y_0
\end{pmatrix}$$
For any **given** $\kappa_0$,
$$L_{\kappa_0}'\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\ y_0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
2\kappa_0x_0 & 0\\
\kappa_0y_0 & \kappa_0x_0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align*}
(L_{\kappa_0}\circ P)'\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\y_0\\a_0\\b_0\\c_0\\d_0
\end{pmatrix}&=L_{\kappa_0}'\left(P\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\y_0\\a_0\\b_0\\c_0\\d_0
\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot P'\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\y_0\\a_0\\b_0\\c_0\\d_0
\end{pmatrix}\\\\\\
&=L_{\kappa_0}'\begin{pmatrix}
a_0x_0+b_0y_0\\c_0x_0+d_0y_0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot P'\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\y_0\\a_0\\b_0\\c_0\\d_0
\end{pmatrix}\\\\\\
&=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
2\kappa_0(a_0x_0+b_0y_0) & 0\\
\kappa_0(c_0x_0+d_0y_0) & \kappa_0(a_0x_0+b_0y_0)
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{a }2\times 2\text{ matrix}}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & b_0 & x_0 & y_0 & 0 & 0\\
c_0 & d_0 & 0 & 0 & x_0 & y_0
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{a }2\times 6\text{ matrix}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Sal Thanks for your tremendous help. I think I will work this out from now on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20758/discussion-on-answer-by-sal-chain-rule-for-vector-valued-function).

Comment: @Sal I have added a new question with the exact sample and my computations - although it seems all formulas are used correctly, the results are different: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130699/chain-rule-and-vector-function